# Anyone have experience with using AMD and NVIDIA GPUs on the same rig?

Tags: gpu-mining

I have just started mining and I have been using a AMD gpu, well I came up on a NIVDIA gpu and I would like to run it beside my AMD gpu. Anyone know How this could be done and with what mining software and settings?

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely possible. You would have to start the AMD and nVidia miners seperately and configure them so that they only used the index of the GPU that they are compatible with. I think in claymore's cryptonight miner it would be 
   -di 02 if you wanted to use GPU 1 and 3. (Computer's use arrays that start at zero to count indices)

As far as I'm aware there are not any nVidia and AMD dual miners for cryptonote algorithm.

Please add more about your operating system for clearer instructions.

Edit: Use ccminer-cryptonight https://github.com/tsiv/ccminer-cryptonight/releases for your nVidia GPU

Use claymore's cryptonight miner for AMD.

If your #1 GPU was AMD and your #2 GPU was nVidia:
claymore would have a "-di 0" flag in the command line or config file
ccminer would have a "-d 1" flag in the command line or bat file

Comment: I am am runing it on windows 10 pro 64bit OS.

Comment: @shamelessApathy I believe you intended this edit for the answer and not for the Q - fixed it for you :)

Comment: ah thank you! Didn't realize I could edit the OP's question, I'll be more careful!

Comment: i would recommend using xmr-stak-nvidia and xmr-stak-amd to be able to have the same commands for both miners, only need to change the device numbers and the block/thread settings

Comment: Thanks for the input I well give these instructions a try if I have any issues I will reply back thanks for the support.